# How to create UI button from SpriteFrames?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

A "Button" can be created by:

```
ui::Button* button = ui::Button::create("button.png");
```

How can we use a sprite sheet for this ?

EDIT: If I just put the name of a sprite frame for example:

```
ui::Button* button = ui::Button::create("button");
```

Then it doesn't detect it - thinks there is a missing image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass an extra argument to the `ui:Button:create` function.

You could use

`ui::Button* button = ui::Button::create("button","","",TextureResType::PLIST);`

to create a button with a sprite frame named "button".

For more information, please refer to the UIButton.h and UIButton.cpp files.

Comment: TextureResType is deprecated now...is there any alternative ?